# Bug found in ChartXY when setting axis to not visible

Tags: lightningchart

I've noticed quite a strange behaviour on LightningChart JS ChartXY if axis x visibility is set to false.

```
axisX.setVisible(false)
```

I'm combining ZoomBandChart with multiple ChartXY's. I just want the axisX to be displayed in the ZoomBandChart, so I'm setting the charts axisX visibility to false. However, if I zoom in, data is displayed outside the charts (in both cases, horizontally and vertically).

I assume it is a bug, although it may also be a coding error.

I'm attaching a screenshot.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeMyd.png)

Comment: The question doesn't really explain what you are doing entirely - surely the entire code is longer than 1 line of code?

Comment: I've found a solution. Instead of using setVisible function to hide the axisX, I'm playinh with the TickStrategy. I'll edit the question with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.

Instead of...

> axisX.setVisible(false)

I've modified the axis TickStrategy to hide it.

```
axisX
    .setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.Numeric, (ticks) => ticks
      .setMajorTickStyle((tickStyle) => tickStyle
        .setLabelFont(new FontSettings({ size: 0 }))
        .setTickLength(0)
        .setTickPadding(2)
      )
      .setMinorTickStyle((tickStyle) => tickStyle
        .setLabelFont(new FontSettings({ size: 0 }))
        .setTickLength(0)
        .setTickPadding(2)
      )
    )
```